# How to disable DEFLATE for one of the IMAP-accounts?

Tags: thunderbird, compression, imap

My home desktop is connected to the mail server via an InfiniBand link -- there is absolutely no point in server compressing the messages and the client inflating them back.

Yet, that's what Thunderbird asks the server to do and the server obliges.

I do want to continue using this feature with *other* IMAP accounts -- so I need some way to disable it per account even if the server advertises the `DEFLATE`-capability.

Is there such a setting somewhere?

Comment: I would assume there's one in your mail server?

Comment: There is, but it is not per-client. When I connect to the same server from iPhone, for example, I'd like `DEFLATE` to be on and working...

Comment: Have you tried to disable the Thunderbird config entry `mail.server.default.use_compress_deflate`?